# Connecting to PostgreSQL Cointainer Database with Airflow DAG

Tags: python, postgresql, docker, airflow, psycopg2

I have issue with connecting to airflow database
I can do it locally with such code

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import os

df = pd.read_csv('wynik_zgloszenia.csv', sep = '#')
engine = create_engine(f'postgresql+psycopg2://postgres:mysecretpassword@localhost:8001/postgres',client_encoding='utf8')
df.to_sql('permissions', engine, index=False, if_exists='replace')
```

I try to reproduce this on DAG, below is my code

```
def permissions_to_sql_db():
    """
    prepare doc-string
    """    
    df = pd.read_csv('/opt/airflow/wynik_zgloszenia.csv', sep='#')    
    engine = create_engine(f'postgresql+psycopg2://postgres:mysecretpassword@postgres:8001/postgres',client_encoding='utf8')
    df.to_sql('permissions', engine, index=False, if_exists='replace')
```

I tried changing localhost to either IP, postgres or db, I tried using port 5432, none of which worked.
**Below the error I get with current code**

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) connection to server at "postgres" (172.27.0.2), port 8001 failed: Connection refused
    Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/e3q8)
```

**edit: Docker compose.yaml below**

```
# Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
# or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
# distributed with this work for additional information
# regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
# to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
# "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
# with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#   http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
# software distributed under the License is distributed on an
# "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
# KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
# specific language governing permissions and limitations
# under the License.
#

# Basic Airflow cluster configuration for CeleryExecutor with Redis and PostgreSQL.
#
# WARNING: This configuration is for local development. Do not use it in a production deployment.
#
# This configuration supports basic configuration using environment variables or an .env file
# The following variables are supported:
#
# AIRFLOW_IMAGE_NAME           - Docker image name used to run Airflow.
#                                Default: apache/airflow:2.8.0
# AIRFLOW_UID                  - User ID in Airflow containers
#                                Default: 50000
# AIRFLOW_PROJ_DIR             - Base path to which all the files will be volumed.
#                                Default: .
# Those configurations are useful mostly in case of standalone testing/running Airflow in test/try-out mode
#
# _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_USERNAME   - Username for the administrator account (if requested).
#                                Default: airflow
# _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_PASSWORD   - Password for the administrator account (if requested).
#                                Default: airflow
# _PIP_ADDITIONAL_REQUIREMENTS - Additional PIP requirements to add when starting all containers.
#                                Use this option ONLY for quick checks. Installing requirements at container
#                                startup is done EVERY TIME the service is started.
#                                A better way is to build a custom image or extend the official image
#                                as described in https://airflow.apache.org/docs/docker-stack/build.html.
#                                Default: ''
#
# Feel free to modify this file to suit your needs.
---
x-airflow-common:
  &airflow-common
  # In order to add custom dependencies or upgrade provider packages you can use your extended image.
  # Comment the image line, place your Dockerfile in the directory where you placed the docker-compose.yaml
  # and uncomment the "build" line below, Then run `docker-compose build` to build the images.
  image: ${AIRFLOW_IMAGE_NAME:-apache/airflow:2.8.0}
  # build: .
  environment:
    &airflow-common-env
    AIRFLOW__CORE__EXECUTOR: LocalExecutor
    AIRFLOW__DATABASE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN: postgresql+psycopg2://airflow:airflow@postgres/airflow
    AIRFLOW__CELERY__RESULT_BACKEND: db+postgresql://airflow:airflow@postgres/airflow
    AIRFLOW__CELERY__BROKER_URL: redis://:@redis:6379/0
    AIRFLOW__CORE__FERNET_KEY: ''
    AIRFLOW__CORE__DAGS_ARE_PAUSED_AT_CREATION: 'true'
    AIRFLOW__CORE__LOAD_EXAMPLES: 'false'
    AIRFLOW__API__AUTH_BACKENDS: 'airflow.api.auth.backend.basic_auth'
    # yamllint disable rule:line-length
    # Use simple http server on scheduler for health checks
    # See https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/administration-and-deployment/logging-monitoring/check-health.html#scheduler-health-check-server
    # yamllint enable rule:line-length
    AIRFLOW__SCHEDULER__ENABLE_HEALTH_CHECK: 'true'
    # WARNING: Use _PIP_ADDITIONAL_REQUIREMENTS option ONLY for a quick checks
    # for other purpose (development, test and especially production usage) build/extend Airflow image.
    _PIP_ADDITIONAL_REQUIREMENTS: ${_PIP_ADDITIONAL_REQUIREMENTS:-}
  volumes:
    - ${AIRFLOW_PROJ_DIR:-.}/dags:/opt/airflow/dags
    - ${AIRFLOW_PROJ_DIR:-.}/logs:/opt/airflow/logs
    - ${AIRFLOW_PROJ_DIR:-.}/config:/opt/airflow/config
    - ${AIRFLOW_PROJ_DIR:-.}/plugins:/opt/airflow/plugins
  user: "${AIRFLOW_UID:-50000}:0"
  depends_on:
    &airflow-common-depends-on
    postgres:
      condition: service_healthy

services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:13
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: airflow
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: airflow
      POSTGRES_DB: airflow
    volumes:
      - postgres-db-volume:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "pg_isready", "-U", "airflow"]
      interval: 10s
      retries: 5
      start_period: 5s
    restart: always

  airflow-webserver:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: webserver
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "--fail", "http://localhost:8080/health"]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
      start_period: 30s
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      <<: *airflow-common-depends-on
      airflow-init:
        condition: service_completed_successfully

  airflow-scheduler:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: scheduler
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "--fail", "http://localhost:8974/health"]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
      start_period: 30s
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      <<: *airflow-common-depends-on
      airflow-init:
        condition: service_completed_successfully

  airflow-triggerer:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: triggerer
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", 'airflow jobs check --job-type TriggererJob --hostname "$${HOSTNAME}"']
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
      start_period: 30s
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      <<: *airflow-common-depends-on
      airflow-init:
        condition: service_completed_successfully

  airflow-init:
    <<: *airflow-common
    entrypoint: /bin/bash
    # yamllint disable rule:line-length
    command:
      - -c
      - |
        if [[ -z "${AIRFLOW_UID}" ]]; then
          echo
          echo -e "\033[1;33mWARNING!!!: AIRFLOW_UID not set!\e[0m"
          echo "If you are on Linux, you SHOULD follow the instructions below to set "
          echo "AIRFLOW_UID environment variable, otherwise files will be owned by root."
          echo "For other operating systems you can get rid of the warning with manually created .env file:"
          echo "    See: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/docker-compose/index.html#setting-the-right-airflow-user"
          echo
        fi
        one_meg=1048576
        mem_available=$$(($$(getconf _PHYS_PAGES) * $$(getconf PAGE_SIZE) / one_meg))
        cpus_available=$$(grep -cE 'cpu[0-9]+' /proc/stat)
        disk_available=$$(df / | tail -1 | awk '{print $$4}')
        warning_resources="false"
        if (( mem_available < 4000 )) ; then
          echo
          echo -e "\033[1;33mWARNING!!!: Not enough memory available for Docker.\e[0m"
          echo "At least 4GB of memory required. You have $$(numfmt --to iec $$((mem_available * one_meg)))"
          echo
          warning_resources="true"
        fi
        if (( cpus_available < 2 )); then
          echo
          echo -e "\033[1;33mWARNING!!!: Not enough CPUS available for Docker.\e[0m"
          echo "At least 2 CPUs recommended. You have $${cpus_available}"
          echo
          warning_resources="true"
        fi
        if (( disk_available < one_meg * 10 )); then
          echo
          echo -e "\033[1;33mWARNING!!!: Not enough Disk space available for Docker.\e[0m"
          echo "At least 10 GBs recommended. You have $$(numfmt --to iec $$((disk_available * 1024 )))"
          echo
          warning_resources="true"
        fi
        if [[ $${warning_resources} == "true" ]]; then
          echo
          echo -e "\033[1;33mWARNING!!!: You have not enough resources to run Airflow (see above)!\e[0m"
          echo "Please follow the instructions to increase amount of resources available:"
          echo "   https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/docker-compose/index.html#before-you-begin"
          echo
        fi
        mkdir -p /sources/logs /sources/dags /sources/plugins
        chown -R "${AIRFLOW_UID}:0" /sources/{logs,dags,plugins}
        exec /entrypoint airflow version
    # yamllint enable rule:line-length
    environment:
      <<: *airflow-common-env
      _AIRFLOW_DB_MIGRATE: 'true'
      _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_CREATE: 'true'
      _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_USERNAME: ${_AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_USERNAME:-airflow}
      _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_PASSWORD: ${_AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_PASSWORD:-airflow}
      _PIP_ADDITIONAL_REQUIREMENTS: ''
    user: "0:0"
    volumes:
      - ${AIRFLOW_PROJ_DIR:-.}:/sources

  airflow-cli:
    <<: *airflow-common
    profiles:
      - debug
    environment:
      <<: *airflow-common-env
      CONNECTION_CHECK_MAX_COUNT: "0"
    # Workaround for entrypoint issue. See: https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/16252
    command:
      - bash
      - -c
      - airflow

  # You can enable flower by adding "--profile flower" option e.g. docker-compose --profile flower up
  # or by explicitly targeted on the command line e.g. docker-compose up flower.
  # See: https://docs.docker.com/compose/profiles/
  flower:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: celery flower
    profiles:
      - flower
    ports:
      - "5555:5555"
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "--fail", "http://localhost:5555/"]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
      start_period: 30s
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      <<: *airflow-common-depends-on
      airflow-init:
        condition: service_completed_successfully

volumes:
  postgres-db-volume:
```

Comment: Please can you provide more context? Presumably your second code sample is being run in a Docker container? Are you using Docker Compose to run PostgreSQL and Airflow? If so, please provide your `docker-compose.yml`. The more information you provide, the more likely you are to get a useful answer.

Comment: Thank you! That gives a lot more context.  Literally a LOT more. Ideally you should try to post a _minimal_ example to illustrate the problem. There are a couple of reasons for this: (1) it makes it quicker and easier for people to see the solution and answer your question and (2) it makes the question/answer more useful because people will be able to rapidly understand the issue and the solution. An added benefit of producing a minimal example is that often you will figure the solution out for yourself in the process of stripping the problem down to the bone.

Comment: Thank you for your contribiution and sorry for late reponse but have been figuring out the problem myself.
Solution posted in other comments.

Answer (score 0):

I'll start building an answer incrementally.

What happens if you reduce your function to the following?

```py
USER = "airflow"
PWD = "airflow"

def permissions_to_sql_db():
    engine = create_engine(
        f"postgresql+psycopg2://{USER}:{PWD}@postgres:5432/postgres",
        client_encoding='utf8'
    )
```

I suspect that you will still have the connection issue? Probably Airflow is not the problem. Your function, `permissions_to_sql_db()`, is that being baked into an image as part of your Docker Compose stack or is it executing "outside" of Docker? Or are you running it in the CLI via the airflow-cli service?

Do the username and password that you're using to connect to the database agree with those specified to the PostgreSQL container? At present the database has `airflow:airflow` but your client code has `postgres:mysecretpassword`.

Port 5432 is the default port for PostgreSQL. If you're accessing the database from outside of the Docker Compose stack then you should expose that port by adding this to the `postgres` service:

```
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
```

Sorry, I feel like this might be more questions than answers. But they'll help us to dive down to the source of the problem.

Comment: I tested this airflow airflow and effect is the same.
Actually I do not want to connect to Airflow's database but separate database which is in different container, thats why I do not think that I need expose line to my postgres service.

Comment: Okay, can you please show how you are launching the separate database? Also, the script that is connecting to the database: is that being run from another container or is it just being run directly on the host machine?

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to connect PostgreSQL in a different container, I believe the problem here is the docker network. My solution is:

- Step 1: Create a docker network with "docker network create my-network"
- Step 2: add all airflow's containers (postgres meta database, scheduler, webserver, triggerer) and the Postgres container to the network you create above (command: "docker network connect network_name container_name" ...)
- Step 3: when all containers are running, run command "docker network inspect my-network" to find your Postgres Container Ip (not the meta database) --> then use that IP to connect to the Database not localhost (like 172.18.0.3/5432 for example)

(the picture below is the result of "docker network inspect my-network" with IP of 4 commponents of airflow, if you add your Postgres you will see it there)

See these 2 links for more examples:

- https://medium.com/@rajat.mca.du.2015/airflow-and-mysql-with-docker-containers-80ed9c2bd340
- https://github.com/cyoung43/airflow-demo

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your contribiution and sorry for late reponse but have been figuring out the problem myself.
Solution posted in other comments.

Answer (score 0):

Actually answer is very straoghtforward.

**All I need to do was to change host from 'localhost' to 'host.docker.internal'**